# Help with Login Table for Large Websites

Tags: database-design

Im new to database an would like to understand how large websites like Facebook and Google handle login for their large user base. I assume Facebook and Google have hundreds of millions or perhaps over a billion user accounts and thousands of people are probably login in at approximately the same time. When someone login, does the system scan the entire user name table to find a match to compare the password? If thats the case, would that take a lot of time? How do they do that in seconds? Or do they somehow index it alphabetically so it does not scan the entire table. How do you index it if the table changes many times a day/hour with new users creating new accounts?

Dibo

Comment: why? Just for fun? what part of his question is answered by that?

Answer (score 1):

Most large companies use systems designed for Identity management. Active Directory is one, site minder is another. Open Id here on stackoverflow is another.

It seems like your real question is how do tables and indexes work.

that's too large a question for SO. But briefly, a database can find a unique entry in a billion row table by reading 3-5 blocks... at 10ms each, that's 30 to 50 milliseconds.

Databases do the index maintenance with each change to the table. It happens concurrently. You don't have to manage it.

Comment: Ok, ill try to make the question simple.  If i have 1 table with hundreds of millions of entries with the primary key being the user/login account (like in google), and a user "johnsmith" logs in, how to make it so that it doesnt search the entire table, which i believe will take a long time.  Also, the user names will continuously be updating.

Comment: Why do you "believe" this is true? have you tried it? If johnsmith is the PK, I think you'll be surprised how long it takes.